# Assigning C# function output-result to VXML variable in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, vxml

I try to create dynamic voice xml document with ASP .NET.

I get a variable in my first page ASP application : **customerRecordId**

```
<%
       int customerRecordId = GetNextAvaliableCustomerId();


 %>
```

**And I want to send this parameter to my second vxml generator  page:**[ProcessAtServer.aspx]

```
<submit maxage="0" method="post"
                       next="http://localhost/ProcessAtServer.aspx"

/>
```

By default vxml submit  all tags like "filled" .But not my variable
customerRecordId.

**PS:** I try namelist at submit : `namelist = "customerRecordId" not worked.`

**How can I send/pass parameter  *customerRecordId* to the page ProcessAtServer.aspx ?**

**More Info:**

Here is general structure of My ASP .NET. What I want is to pass the result of Function GetNextAvaliableCustomerId as parameter to post request [ using submit tag ]

```
<script language="c#" runat="server">


 public int GetNextAvaliableCustomerId()
 {
    // Some Code
 }

</script>

<% Response.ContentType="text/xml"; %><?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<vxml version="2.0">

  <%-- This DOES NOT WORK. 
       GET COMPILATION ERROR "Compiler Error Message: CS1002: ; expected"  
  --%>
 <var name="customerRecordId" expr="<%GetNextAvailableCustomerId()%>"/> 

<form>

    <field name ="option">

         // SomeCOde          
        <submit maxage="0" method="post"
                           next="http://localhost:49368/ProcessSurveyResult.aspx"
                           namelist ="option"
        />

        // Some code
</filled>
</form>
</vxml>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting *customerRecordId* in the *namelist* will not work because it is not part of the vxml.  Try something like this:

```
<var name="customerRecordId" expr="<% =GetNextAvailableCustomerId() %>" />
```

Then you can use the *namelist* attribute in the *submit* element to pass the variable in query string.

If you are new to VoiceXML and what to use ASP.NET to generate dynamic pages I would suggest looking at the open source project [VoiceModel](http://voicemodel.codeplex.com/). There are a lot of examples in the project to help you get started.

Comment: When I try this in My ASP .NET application I get "Compiler Error Message: CS1002: ; expected" Error at " <var name="customerRecordId" expr="<%GetNextAvailableCustomerId()%>"/> "

Comment: just put extra "="... <var name="customerRecordId" expr="<%= GetNextAvailableCustomerId() %>" /> and it worked. :-)

Comment: You are just missing the semi-colon after GetNextAvailableCustomerId(). I updated my answer to show the correct syntax. You also need to add customerRecordId to the namelist in the submit element.

Comment: Well it does not work in your  way.I used this and worked : . <var name="customerRecordId" expr="<%= GetNextAvailableCustomerId() %>" Extra "="

Comment: Hippias - You are correct, you need the equals sign. Without the equals sign it just runs the function without returning the value. And if you use the equals sign the semi-colon is not required.